# Unable to store a python class object in postgres database

Tags: django, python-3.x, postgresql

I have a class defined like below

```
class StatementStatus:
    def __init__(self, id, statement, call, intent, score):
        self.id = callback_id
        self.statement = statement
        self.entities = entities
        self.intent = intent
        self.score = score

    def getIntent(self):
        return self.intent

    def getScore(self):
        return self.score

    def addIntent(self, intent_val):
        self.intent.append(intent_val)
```

Now I want to store an instance of this class into postgres database.This file is hosted in a django server and I am unable to use django migrations due to some issues in the server.So I need to do it manually.

Below is my django model

```
class StoreState(models.Model):
    context_name = models.CharField(null=True,max_length=100)
    state = models.BinaryField(null=True)
```

Here I want to store the StatementStatus instance in a field called state.

Similarly my postgres table structure looks like below

```
    Column    |          Type          | Modifiers 
--------------+------------------------+-----------
 id           | integer                | 
 context_name | character varying(100) | 
 state        | bytea                  |
```

But it doesn't store any entry into the table when I do an operation like below

```
try:
    conv = StoreState.objects.create(
    context_name = callback_id,
    state=s
    )
except Exception as e:
    print("unable to save update", e)
```

But it doesn't store anything into the table.I get the below error.

```
('unable to save update', TypeError("can't escape instance to binary",))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: your state is not a binary object. it is just an instance object

Comment: @HarunERGUL oh ok so how do I store an instance object?

Comment: can you show us where s coming from?

Comment: I think you should create a StatementStatus table and use ForeingKey in your Storestate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to save your object in your database then use pickle.

```
import pickle
state = pickle.dump(state) #your state object will be converted to binary

try:
    conv = StoreState.objects.create(
    context_name = callback_id,
    state=s
      )
except Exception as e:
    print("unable to save update", e)
```